# Open popup with javascript .link() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.open, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid to display JSON data.  If values are held in nested objects I have to use a valueGetter (grid API) to map to the value.  The value getter returns a value per row and the grid assigns the correct value to the correct row.  Problem is I need each value to be a hyperlink, which opens a popup.  I have an openPopup() method which uses window.open.  However AFAIK I'm forced to use javascripts .link() method, which only takes a URL string so I can't figure out how to open the link in a new window.

Value getter :

```
function isinValueGetterBox(params) {
    if (params.node.group) { return null; }
    var isinValueBox = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < params.data.security.identifiers.length; i++) {
        if (params.data.security.identifiers[i].type === "isin") {
            isinValueBox = params.data.security.identifiers[i].value;
        }
    }
    return isinValueBox.link("views/Popup1.html");
}
```

popup method :

```
popup1 = function () {
    var popup1 = window.open("views/Popup1.html", "_blank",
                        "height = 400, width = 700");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it's possible to utilize HTML from within javascript when creating a string, so I simply attached an `<a>` tag with an `onclick` to call my window.open method.

New valueGetter method :

```
 function isinValueGetterBox(params) {
    if (params.node.group) { return null; }
    var isinValueBox = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < params.data.security.identifiers.length; i++) {
        if (params.data.security.identifiers[i].type === "isin") {
            isinValueBox = ('<a href = "#" onclick = popup1()>' + params.data.security.identifiers[i].value + '</a>');
        }
    }
    return isinValueBox;
}
```